# Using threads to print out words depending on the starting character

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've had a hard time finding information online on using threads in C++. What I need my program to do is create two threads in the main(). These two threads take words from a sentence specified in a text file and print out the the words depending on the starting character of each word. One thread should print the words starting with a vowel and the other thread should print the words starting with consonants. The main() shouldn't print anything itself and the order of the words should remain the same from the sentence. The two threads are required to yield to each other to accomplish this. No synchronization techniques can be used.

I have the text file being read into a vector and that is working fine currently. My code can accomplish getting the correct output, but not in the manner specified. If you can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void cons(string temp){
    if (temp[0] != 'A' && temp[0] != 'a' && temp[0] != 'E'&& temp[0] != 'e'&& temp[0] != 'I'&& temp[0] != 'i'&& temp[0] != 'O'&& temp[0] != 'o'&& temp[0] != 'U'&& temp[0] != 'u') {
        cout << "cons:  " << temp << endl;
    }
    this_thread::yield();
}

void vow(string temp){
    if (temp[0] == 'A'|| temp[0] == 'a'|| temp[0] == 'E'|| temp[0] == 'e'|| temp[0] == 'I'|| temp[0] == 'i'|| temp[0] == 'O'|| temp[0] == 'o'|| temp[0] == 'U'|| temp[0] == 'u') { 
        cout << "vow:   " << temp << endl;
    }
    this_thread::yield();
}


int main(){
    string sentence, temp;
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ofs;
    vector <thread> wordThreads;

    ifs.open("phrase.txt");
    getline(ifs, sentence);
    istringstream s(sentence);
    istream_iterator<string> begin(s), end;
    vector<string> words(begin, end); 

    ifs.close();

    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        wordThreads.push_back(thread(cons, words[i]));
        wordThreads.push_back(thread(vow, words[i]));
    }

    for (thread& t: wordThreads) // loop with a range variable
    t.join(); 
}
```

Comment: The yields should be unnecessary, the threads are going to yield anyways once the functions end

Comment: They do seem unnecessary given that with them nothing seems to change. If I got rid of everything below "ifs.close();" and changed it to "thread one(cons, words[i]), two(vow, words[i]); one.join(); two.join();" then I believe it prints everything correctly. Currently it prints in a random manner which I know is the case with threads, but at least it doesn't leave anything out.

Comment: @mwigdahl: please read the homework tag wiki.

Comment: *"My code can accomplish getting the correct output, but not in the manner specified."* Please elaborate on this. Hint: What happens if you put `yield` inside of your `for`-loop?

Comment: Well I guess the best way to put it is...you see what I have here? Do you feel it satisfies how I described it should be done? If not then what needs changed? I'll try what you mentioned and see what comes of it.

Comment: If I add a yield into the for loop I still get a random ordered output of the words. If I run the code as you see it above I get the same thing. How can I get the output to be in order as it appears in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old topic, but the answer here is to use `Petersons` algorithm in the following function:

```
loop
 flag[i] := true;   
 turn := j;    
 while flag[j] and turn = j do nothing;
 (critical section of code)  
 flag[i] := false;  
 (remainder section of code)   
end loop
```

which controls when the switching should occur based on a Bool array of flags and a turn variable, both located in the global shared memory space. No mutex's used.